# Entity Framework - SaveChanges with GUID as EntityKey

Tags: entity-framework, guid

I have a SQL Server 2008 database table that uses uniqueidentifier as a primary key. On inserts, the key is generated on the database side using the newid() function.

This works fine with ADO.NET. But when I set up this table as an entity in an Entity Framework 4 model, there's a problem. I am able to query the entity just fine, but when creating a new entity and invoking SaveChanges() on the context, the generated uniqueidentifier on the database is all zeros.

I understand there was an issue with EF v1 where this scenario did not work, requiring creating the GUID on the client prior to calling SaveChanges. However, I had read in many places that they were planning to fix this in EF 4.

My question -- is this scenario (DB-side generation of uniqueidentifier) still not supported in EF4? Are we still stuck with generating the GUID on the client?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you feel you're "stuck" with generating the GUID on the client? This is the primary *advantage* of uniqueidentifier, IMO. If you want to generate IDs on the server, why not just use an auto-increment key?

Comment: Great nickname, by the way. :)

Comment: @MusiGenesis, 1. MissingLinq does want a auto generated key, just not an int (perhaps since they have more limited ranges). 2. The point of database generated keys is to eliminate collisions, with a GUID the chance of that may be 1/2^128, but why not let the database do that and let the client code just worry about creating the entities and not about database keys.

Comment: @Danny: there are performance costs (usually overstated, but still) involved with using a GUID PK instead of an auto-incremented int. IMHO, these costs are compensated for by the ability to create new records in a disconnected client without having to connect to the database. If you're not using GUIDs for disconnected clients, there's not much left except the disadvantages.

Comment: @MusiGenesis Uniqueidentifiers have another advantage over autoincrementing integers in a table with many crud operations. Often, inserts and updates occur on the most recently added records. With ints, these will be on the final page of the clustered index, creating a hotspot of activity and page locking contention. With Guids, the newly created records are most likely spread around the leaf nodes of the index, so, although the search times will be VERY slightly slower, this will be more than compensated for by the high throughput. As in all cases with SQL table design, test, test and test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks guys, finally got it figured out. Blogged the answer here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20100518175148/http://leedumond.com/blog/using-a-guid-as-an-entitykey-in-entity-framework-4/

Comment: Does Microsoft have any plans to tweak the designer to support this?
Opening up the .edmx file is troublesome at best.

Comment: +1 Your solution works, too bad the EF team didn't make it simpler though.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this changed in EF 4. [You can now use a server generated GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283139.aspx). @MusiGenesis, server-generated GUIDs have some advantages; they can be sequential, e.g.

Comment: Craig - I've seen that link. It says that "the provider must be able to return the server-generated identity value after a row is inserted. SQL Server can return the server-generated GUID type through the OUTPUT clause starting with SQL Server 2005."

This seems to indicate to me that a stored procedure would be required. I was actually wanting to know if this is supported natively, and if so, why am I getting a "null" (all-zeros) identifier?

Comment: No, [OUTPUT works with INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx). Look at the generated INSERT and make sure it includes OUTPUT>